# setInterval slows down in chrome after unsubscribe and re-subscribe

Tags: javascript, rxjs

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@^7/dist/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        /*let {interval, take  } = rxjs;
        interval(1000).pipe(take(1500)).subscribe(x => console.log("Next->",x));*/
    </script>
    <script>
        let {Observable}  = rxjs;
        var cancellableObserver = Observable.create((observer)=>{
             let i = 0;
             const handler = setInterval(() => {
                if(i++ < 1500) {
                   //console.log("Next->", i)
                   observer.next(i);
               } else {
                   clearInterval(handler);
               }
             }, 1000);
             return () => {
                console.log("Unsubscribing");
                i = 0;
                clearInterval(handler);
             }
        });
        let cancellableSubscription = cancellableObserver.subscribe(x => console.log("Next=>", x));
        setTimeout(() => {
            cancellableSubscription.unsubscribe();
            cancellableSubscription = cancellableObserver.subscribe(x => console.log("Next12=>", x));
            setTimeout(() => {
                cancellableSubscription.unsubscribe();
                cancellableSubscription = cancellableObserver.subscribe(x => console.log("Next123=>", x));
            }, 15000);
        },15000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above code till 15 seconds, the observer emits observable every 1 sec. After unsubscribe and re-subscribe, in chrome observable emits approx every 2 seconds. It slows down. Is it possible to stop the slowdown and emit observable every 1 sec?

Please save the html as a file in desktop and launch in chrome. You will see the issue in developer console.

I see issues with the interval() method provided by rxjs7. Sometimes it abruptly stops and re-starts. For e.g. it got stuck at 300 secs for about 2-3 mins and starts from 301. So refactoring to use setInterval.

If you do run code snippet it works fine. Only in chrome dev console this issue happening.